# How to show a column conditionally in backpack for laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I need show a column conditionally, based on user permission in backpack for laravel.
[image]

Need to show `customer` and `total` column only for admin.
In documentation I found `visibleInShow`, But do not know how to use it.

Note: **I need to make the column unvisible with header.**

```
CRUD::column('user')->label('Customer');
CRUD::modifyColumn('user', [
           'name' => 'user',
           'type' => 'closure',
        ]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually `visibleInShow` is used mostly in special cases like "hide a column from the listing, but still export it" or "hide a column from listing but still allow searching on it".

Based on your question this is how I conditionally hide columns:

```
protected function setupListOperation()
{
    // Other columns setup (skipped)
    
    if (Auth::user()->isAdmin) {
        CRUD::column('user')->label('Customer');
    }

    // More columns setup (skipped)
}
```

or to put it simple: only add the column when the condition is met.
No need to add the column and then add more logic to hide it.